# Is there a way to make GNU Screen not prompt for confirmation?

Tags: linux, command-line, gnu-screen

My googling only left me the clue that this was the case for old `screen`, and now the new `screen` prompts for confirmation (e.g. whenever I try to kill a window or exit out of screen) . Is there a variable or remapping that will eliminate prompting? Also is there a remapping that will save me the trouble of deleting the window name when I try to rename it?

```
Screen version 4.00.03 (FAU) 23-Oct-06
```

Comment: I assume you are referring to GNU screen running on Linux?

Comment: yes! I changed the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real answer. The workaround:

- use `exit` in the shell instead of <kbd>ctrl-k</kbd>
- never rename your window: Use following [script](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdtfm.tumblr.com%2Fpost%2F7193076007&ei=yBhOUeeiBYasigLr2YFA&usg=AFQjCNFi2CSe_aDa-AUPt5DDIVJfmrumDQ&sig2=V4HEfT0ZmHr69KMR7MBx-A) (or something similar)

  ```
  case $TERM in
  screen*)
      SCREENTITLE='\[\ek\e\\\]\[\ek\W\e\\\]'
      ;;
  *)
      SCREENTITLE=''
      ;;
  esac
  export PS1="${SCREENTITLE}[\u@\h \W]\$ "
  ```

Comment: Where can I find the grammar of the title?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative way to rename the current window. It resolves your issue with having to delete the existing window name, however, it doesn't save any keystrokes.

<kbd>Control+a</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> (puts screen in command mode)
:`title <new window name>`

Answer (score 0):

Go into `sudo vim /etc/screenrc` and update `startup_message off`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).